# What does "Gromov Witten potential" the "potential" mean

Tags: algebraic-geometry, physics

"Gromov Witten potential", when does "potential" mean here? What does the whole thing mean in physics? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Gromov-Witten potential is a generating function for Gromov-Witten numbers, which are integrals of Gromov-Witten classes over the moduli space. According to Kontsevich and Manin this numbers define all the classes under some rather general assumptions. This potential defines a structure of formal Frobenius manifold on the cohomology. This is an example of cohomological field theory. Standard refernce is the book *Frobenius manifolds, quantum cohomology and moduli spaces*, written by Yuri Manin.